# proof that $1/2 \ln x = \ln(\sqrt x)$ where $x>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is a proof that $1/2 \ln x = \ln(\sqrt x)$ where $x>0$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a\ln(x)=\ln(x^a)$ why ?

if $\ln(x)=b$ and $\ln(x^a)=c,x^a=e^c,x=e^b$ so $e^c=e^{ab}$so $c=ab$
$$\ln(x^a)=ba=a\ln(x)$$

Comment: You of course also need that $\sqrt x$ is the same as $(x)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 3):

$$
ln x = \int_1^x  \frac{dt}{t}
$$
(set $t=q^2$)
$$
= \int_1^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{2qdq}{q^2} = 2 \int_1^{\sqrt{x}} \frac{dq}{q} = 2 ln \sqrt{x}
$$